# CosmosDB : CosmosPatchOperation not working via Stored Procedure

Tags: java, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I want to replace cosmos batch with Stored Proc as my requirement is to upsert 100+ records which cosmos batch does not support. I am adding 2 java objects and 1 CosmosPatchOperations
in List and passing to below method.Whenver I am adding cosmos patch object no rows got inserted/updated otherwise it is working fine.I want to perform both insertion and patch operation in same transaction. Can somebody please guide how to modify SP so that it supports both insert and patch operation.

```
  String rowsUpserted = "";
    try
    {
      rowsUpserted = container
              .getScripts()
              .getStoredProcedure("createEvent")
              .execute(Arrays.asList(listObj), options)
              .getResponseAsString();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Stored Proc

```
function createEvent(items) {

var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var collectionLink = collection.getSelfLink();
var count = 0;

if (!items) throw new Error("The array is undefined or null.");

var numItems = items.length;

if (numItems == 0) {
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(0);
    return;
}

tryCreate(items[count], callback);

function tryCreate(item, callback) {
    var options = { disableAutomaticIdGeneration: false };

    var isAccepted = collection.upsertDocument(collectionLink, item, options, callback);
    
    

    if (!isAccepted) getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
}

function callback(err, item, options) {
    if (err) throw err;
    count++;
    if (count >= numItems) {
        getContext().getResponse().setBody(count);
    } else {
        tryCreate(items[count], callback);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting now

Comment: @Sajeetharan no rows getting upserted (2 rows were expected to get insert and 1 update). No exception is being thrown . If I remove CosmosPatchOperation from listObj then 2 rows are getting inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Patching doesn't appear to be supported by the `Collection` type in the Javascript stored proc API. I suspect this was done as it's more an optimisiation for remote calls and SP execute locally so it's not really neccessary.

API reference is here: http://azure.github.io/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/Collection.html

`upsertDocument` is expecting the full document.

Answer (score 0):

@Loren - patch operations are supported within stored procedures. Please see this Microsoft documentation: [Get started with Azure Cosmos DB Partial Document Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partial-document-update-getting-started?tabs=dotnet#support-for-server-side-programming). You want to skip the first JavaScript example and go to the one right after "Sample stored procedure for patch operation".

Just in case that documentation ever disappears, here's the sample stored procedure:

```
function patchDemo() {
    var doc = {
        "id": "exampleDoc",
        "fields": {
            "field1": "exampleString",
            "field2": 20,
            "field3": 40
        }
    };
    
    var isAccepted = __.createDocument(__.getSelfLink(), doc, (err, doc) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            getContext().getResponse().setBody("Example document successfully created.");
            
            var patchSpec = [
                { "op": "add", "path": "/fields/field1", "value": "newExampleString" },
                { "op": "remove", "path": "/fields/field2" },
                { "op": "incr", "path": "/fields/field3", "value": 10 }
            ];
            
            var isAccepted = __.patchDocument(doc._self, patchSpec, (err, doc) => {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                else {
                    getContext().getResponse().appendBody(" Example document successfully patched.");
                }
            });
            
            if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("Patch wasn't accepted");
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("Create wasn't accepted.");
}
```